# WiX: How to register application to start when Windows launches?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I'm exploring distribution of .NET desktop applications with MSI generated by WiX.

So far it works great. But I've got a few questions, googling can't help out with.

**What's the advised way of registering application to start when windows launches (in WiX)?**

What WixUI could I use and how?

Notes:

- The application is not a Windows Service and should not be registered as such.
- It would be nice to let user to disable that option in the setup process.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I [found this using Google](http://www.merlinia.com/mdt/WiXTutorial4.msl) (Providing automatic program start via the Registry); it also  includes adding UI. Don't forget you should also provide an option outside the setup to enable/disable autostart.

The basic Wix for it is:

```
  <Property Id="ASSISTANCE_START_VIA_REGISTRY">1</Property>

  <!-- Auto-start via Registry -->
  <Component Id="MerliniAssistanceAutostart" Guid="Place-your-own-GUID-here">
    <RegistryValue Id="MerAs.rst" Root="HKMU" Action="write"
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
                   Name="Merlinia Assistance Client"
                   Value="[INSTALLDIR]Assistance.exe"
                   Type="string" />
    <Condition>ASSISTANCE_START_VIA_REGISTRY</Condition>
  </Component>

  <ComponentRef Id="MerliniaAssistanceAutostart" />
```

Comment: Apparently there are some benefits to starting off a shortcut instead of directly off the .exe.

Comment: @tofutim Care to elaborate more?

Comment: If AutoStart points to the lnk in the StartMenu, you could modify the Start Menu shortcut parameters and have AutoStart start that version.

Comment: If you give your `<File/>` an Id, you can put `[#FileId]` as the `Value` instead of `[INSTALLDIR]Assistance.exe`. That way, if you change the name of the exe file, or its location or whatever, that field will be automatically updated and kept in sync.

Comment: I tried this, but the Application did not start on startup by this. Is there a known issue ?

Comment: I suppose Root="HKMU" should be Root="HKCU"…

Answer (score 13):

Take a look in the registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.  If you want it to start per-user then look in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.  If you want it to start when Windows starts, without requiring a user to log on, that's a Service.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you ask the user with a custom form if the application should startup automatically and then create a link in the users startup folder.

Comment: why -1? With WiX it is easy to create a link in users startup folder?

Comment: ...and you failed to provide the example the user was looking for.

Comment: Oh @aaron, there was a time when giving examples was bad habit here as long as the OP did not show his code first. Keyword homework!

Comment: I bow to your higher reputation.  ;)